# How to supress all warnings when running pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, warnings

Some warning can cause problems when running tests with pytest. It might be desirable to ignore all warnings. I could not find a clear way to suppress all warnings.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to catch and test specific warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
pytest -W ignore test_script.py
```

Answer (score 11):

You can run the following command:

```
pytest --disable-warnings
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting the code below to `[pytest]` in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) can disable all warnings. *You can see [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html#disabling-warning-capture-entirely)

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest] # ↓ Here ↓
addopts = -p no:warnings
```

Or, running the command below can disable all warnings. *You can see [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html#disabling-warnings-summary):

```
pytest --disable-warnings
```